# ionic app getting compiled and on building getting error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, ionic3

hi i am new to ionic and i had build an app using ionic, it had running while i am compiling on my PC and when i am trying to run the app using ionic cordova run android it was showing error and i found that all the variables i am using as the errors and i am unable to build the app too. so plz anyone help me with this issue
thank q in advance
This is the error i am getting

```
[12:00:54]  typescript: src/pages/find-genie4/find-genie4.ts, line: 31 
            Argument of type '{ headers: { 'Authorization': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
            'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type '{ 'Authorization': string; }' is 
            not assignable to type 'Headers'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Authorization'' 
            does not exist in type 'Headers'. 

      L30:  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
      L31:  this.http.get('https://api.findgenie.org/v1/my-requests/',{headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '+token.token}}
      L32:     this.posts = data.json().data.user_requests;

[12:00:54]  typescript: src/pages/find-genie4/find-genie4.ts, line: 32 
            Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'FindGenie4Page'. 

      L31:  this.http.get('https://api.findgenie.org/v1/my-requests/',{headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '+token.token}}).subscribe(data => {
      L32:     this.posts = data.json().data.user_requests;
      L33:     this.rating = data.json().data.user_details.rating;

[12:00:54]  typescript: src/pages/find-genie4/find-genie4.ts, line: 33 
            Property 'rating' does not exist on type 'FindGenie4Page'. 

      L32:  this.posts = data.json().data.user_requests;
      L33:  this.rating = data.json().data.user_details.rating;
      L34:  console.log("this.posts",this.posts)

[12:00:54]  typescript: src/pages/find-genie4/find-genie4.ts, line: 34 
            Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'FindGenie4Page'. 

      L33:      this.rating = data.json().data.user_details.rating;
      L34:      console.log("this.posts",this.posts)
      L35:  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append headers like this, use `HttpHeaders` class to send headers. In your response data, declare the type of it as `any`

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Token '+token.token
  })
};

this.http.get('https://api.findgenie.org/v1/my-requests/',httpOptions ).subscribe((data: any) => {
       this.posts = data.json().data.user_requests;
       this.rating = data.json().data.user_details.rating;
 });
```